# How to extract url and label from String <a> tag?

Tags: java

I have a List of `<a>` tags of the String format `<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>`.
What is the best way to extract the url `http://example.com` and the label `Example` from this String.
Currenty I use substring method to identify boundaries and fetch the url and the label. But is there a better way using regular expression?

Comment: You may also use split() on the quote sign -> "

Comment: I would use a html parser and get the value of the attribute href of the element a.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to extract the values from the html.

They provide an example with almost exactly what you want [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jsoup.org").get();

Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String relHref = link.attr("href"); // == "/"
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // "http://jsoup.org/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you would go with one of the good HTML parsers. i.e. JSoup.

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex for this:

**"\\"(.*?)\"\"** *(extracts string between apostrophes)*

Although I would recommend you used a tool that is specific for HTML attribute extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache commons [substringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.